# how to get data data from datalayer.push using python webscraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

my code us:

```
        # init scrapy selector
        response = Selector(text=content)
        
        json_data = json.loads(script.get() for script in (re.findall(r'dataLayer\.push\(([^)]+)'),response.css('script::text'))).group(1)
        print(json_data)
    
    # debug data extraction logic
    HummartScraper.parse_product(HummartScraper, '')
```

'
the output error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hummart2.py", line 86, in parse_product
    json_data = json.loads(script.get() for script in (re.findall(r'dataLayer\.push\(([^)]+)'),response.css('script::text'))).group(1)
TypeError: findall() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'
```

why is this error getting.

Answer (score 1):

For a single `dataLayer`:

```
data_layer = response.css('script::text').re_first(r'dataLayer\.push\(([^)]+)')
data = json.loads(data_layer)
```

You can use `response.css(...).re()` to get a list of matches.

Comment: File "hummart2.py", line 88, in parse_product
    data = json.loads(data_layer_raw)[1]
  File "/home/danish-khan/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 341, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType

Comment: Looks like your regular expression is wrong. Could you show me a source page?

Comment: this is the souce page:   'view-source:https://hummart.com/crispo-banana-custard-120-gm.html'

Comment: ok thank you its ok now done with your code.